# Ionic Show Google Map Result from Json file

Tags: json, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am doing an assignment. There is one scenario that user search for companies' name, etc. Then user click the result --> shows company details which include map. I would like to know how to pass json file's location data(a long list,I just paste hereinbelow a short one) to the view. Also, how to make a mark on the showed map. I used setCenter but got wrong result. tks for your reply in advance. Attach here js, html and css.

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(pos) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.785091, -73.968285);
 
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
 
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
 
        $scope.map = map;
    });
 
});


/// There is no place anymore, so I paste the Json file here:

{
   "data": [{

        "office_id": "1",
        "name": "Demo Office",
        "shortname":"demo",
        "address": "somewhere",
        "latitude": "64.49815080",
        "longitude": "28.76102540",
        "active": "1",
        "locked": "0"
    }, {
        "office_id": "2",
        "name": "Health Center",
        "shortname":"health",
        "address": "Thailand",
        "latitude": "61.19945900",
        "longitude": "25.65550300",
        "active": "1",
        "locked": "0"
   
    }],
    "status": 0,
    "message": "some message",
    "messageID": 0
}
```

```css
/* Empty. Add your own CSS if you like */
.scroll {
    height: 100%;
}
 
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter">
        <ion-pane>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
                <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>

              <ion-content ng-controller="MapController">
                  <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
                  
              </ion-content>
                         
        </ion-pane>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[my api key]&sensor=true"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to access JSON objects http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar Google Map related question the other day, scroll do to the answer and see how I implemented the json data. Any problems let me know.

[AngularJS Google Map with Multiple Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891296/angularjs-google-map-with-multiple-markers?noredirect=1#comment47911091_29891296)