# AngularJS Google Map with Multiple Markers

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an Ionic Framework (AngularJS) project which uses Geo Location and Google Maps for displaying the user's position.

I'm trying to display the users Geo Location and multiple markers around the area.

I've got the Geo Location working, but can't seem to add multiple markers.

**Locations**

```
var markers = [
    {'London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562},
    {'Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755}
];
```

**Controller.JS**

```
// 1. Google Map // 
FCCAppCtrl.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.initialise = function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
            var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: "My Location"
            });
        });
        $scope.map = map;
    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.initialise());
});
```

Comment: You have an array `markers` but I don't see anywhere in your Controller that references that... is there some additional code missing from your question?  Presumably you don't need that to be part of the geolocation request; just loop over the markers array in your initialise function, adding a new Marker for each

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// 1. Google Map // 
var cities = [
    {
        city : 'Location 1',
        desc : 'Test',
        lat : 52.238983,
        long : -0.888509 
    },
    {
        city : 'Location 2',
        desc : 'Test',
        lat : 52.238168,
        long : -52.238168
    },
    {
        city : 'Location 3',
        desc : 'Test',
        lat : 52.242452,
        long : -0.889882 
    },
    {
        city : 'Location 4',
        desc : 'Test',
        lat : 52.247234,
        long : -0.893567 
    },
    {
        city : 'Location 5',
        desc : 'Test',
        lat : 52.241874,
        long : -0.883568 
    }
];

FCCAppCtrl.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
    // Map Settings //
    $scope.initialise = function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
      // Geo Location /
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
            var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: "My Location"
            });
        });
        $scope.map = map;
        // Additional Markers //
        $scope.markers = [];
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var createMarker = function (info){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
                map: $scope.map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: info.city
            });
            marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
                infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            });
            $scope.markers.push(marker);
        }  
        for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
            createMarker(cities[i]);
        }

    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.initialise());

});
```

Comment: Good solution. I have one question. Why do we need to store the markers? '$scope.markers.push(marker);'? Is this really necessary?

Comment: markers not working for me. Can please provide html css also .(I am new to this)

Answer (score 4):

here is the complete js file , you can just copy paste this

```
var myItemsApp = angular.module('myItemsApp', []);

myItemsApp.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
var itemsFactory = {
    itemDetails: function () {
        return $http({
                url: "pos.json",
                method: "GET"

            })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
            });
    }
};
return itemsFactory;

}]);




 myItemsApp.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory', function ($scope, itemsFactory) {
var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.itemDetails = data;
    console.log(data);
});
$scope.select = function (item) {
    $scope.selected = item;
};
$scope.selected = {};

$scope.selected.latitude;
 }]);


 myItemsApp.directive("myMaps", function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watchCollection('selected', function () {
            var lat = scope.selected.latitude;
            var lon = scope.selected.longitude;

            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatLng,
                zoom: 12,
                myTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: "my town"
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        });

    }
};
 });
```

its tested , i hope it will work for you , let me know if you need any help 
by the way here is the json file for better understanding

```
{
"snappedPoints": [
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.2784167,
            "longitude": 149.1294692
        },
        "originalIndex": 0,
        "placeId": "ChIJoR7CemhNFmsRQB9QbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.280321693840129,
            "longitude": 149.12908274880189
        },
        "originalIndex": 1,
        "placeId": "ChIJiy6YT2hNFmsRkHZAbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.2803415,
            "longitude": 149.1290788
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJiy6YT2hNFmsRkHZAbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.2803415,
            "longitude": 149.1290788
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.280451499999991,
            "longitude": 149.1290784
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.2805167,
            "longitude": 149.1290879
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.2805901,
            "longitude": 149.1291104
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.2805901,
            "longitude": 149.1291104
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.280734599999995,
            "longitude": 149.1291517
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.2807852,
            "longitude": 149.1291716
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.2808499,
            "longitude": 149.1292099
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.280923099999995,
            "longitude": 149.129278
        },
        "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
},
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.280960897210818,
            "longitude": 149.1293250692261
        },
        "originalIndex": 2,
        "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
},

    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": -35.284728724835304,
            "longitude": 149.12835061713685
        },
        "originalIndex": 7,
        "placeId": "ChIJW5JAZmpNFmsRegG0-Jc80sM"
}
]
```

Comment: can you please provide html css also OR if possible git repo url